# Setup Auto reply for a contact in exchange 2010

Tags: email, exchange-2010, auto-reply

I am trying to setup an auto reply bounce back for an email contact from exchange management console.

1. Is it possible?
2. If it is possible please instruct me how.

I tried to setup a new "Transport Rule" but I am missing the "Send a bounce back email,,," option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what you are trying to accomplish but it is probably best you use an Out of Office message.  You can apply it from an administrative account by following this article:

[Configure Automatic Replies for a user in Exchange 2010](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2011/09/08/configure-automatic-replies-for-a-user-in-exchange-2010.aspx)

From the article:

> You must be a member of a role group that has either the Mail
>   Recipients or User Options management roles.
>
> This command schedules internal and external auto-replies from
>   9/8/2011 to 9/15/2011:
>
> ```
> Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration bsuneja@e14labs.com –AutoReplyState
> Scheduled –StartTime “9/8/2011” –EndTime “9/15/2011” –ExternalMessage
> “External OOF message here” –InternalMessage “Internal OOF message
> here”
> ```

Comment: Thanks I was hoping to get this working straight from exchange. And remember this is a contact not a mailbox.

Comment: I believe your only other option is a Transport Rule, but you said you are missing the "send rejection message to sender..."?

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I just turned that contact into a mailbox with an auto responder and it worked.